# How to set environment PATH in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline bat block

Tags: jenkins, path, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to set the environment PATH variable in a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline and am trying to use the same in a bat block on a windows machine. (I'm  trying to modify the path so that I can use the same to call an executable without explicitly specifying the path.)
The path does not get passed to the bat block for some reason. 
Any pointers to what could be the issue is highly appreciated from all you experienced developers out there. Thanks in advance!

Following is my code.

```
    pipeline {
      agent { label 'docker' }
      environment {
        PATH = "/hot/new/bin:$PATH"
      }
      stages {
        stage ('build') {
          steps {
            echo "PATH is: $PATH"
            bat """
                echo PATH is: %PATH%
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Output is as follows:

```
PATH is: /hot/new/bin:blah:blah:my_env_path_content_remianing
PATH is: blah:blah:blah:my_env_path_content_remianing
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using this syntax to make groovy able to interpolate the variable ?

```
bat """
    echo PATH is: ${env.PATH}
"""
```

Or like this:

```
bat "echo PATH is: ${env.PATH}"
```